# FullContact batch request using RestSharp

Tags: post, restsharp, fullcontact

How can we implement batch request processing in FullContact api using RestSharp.
A sample post request for the batch request in the FullContact api is given as

```
POST /v2/batch.json?apiKey=[your API key] HTTP/1.1
Content-type: application/json
Host: api.fullcontact.com
Content-Length: 236
Connection: Keep-Alive

{
 "requests" :
  [
    "https://api.fullcontact.com/v2/name/normalizer.json?q=dan+lynn",
    "https://api.fullcontact.com/v2/name/normalizer.json?q=kyle+hansen",
    "https://api.fullcontact.com/v2/person.json?email=bart@fullcontact.com"
  ]
}
```

link : [FullContact api batch request](https://www.fullcontact.com/developer/docs/batch/)

Can any one help on how to make multiple requests like this using RestSharp